# Using directed centrifugal force to create continuous acceleration

Tags: rotational-dynamics, momentum, energy-conservation, centrifugal-force, perpetual-motion

This is something that I've been curious about for a while now, and please understand I'm not a physicist by trade.

I began this thought experiment thinking about how I've seen vibrations generated in electronic devices. Unless I'm completely wrong, I've seen it done with a rotating weight.

That rotating weight makes the phone bounce back and force, even if just a little.

Now iterating on that concept, imagine a rotating object that could change it's speed or radius of rotation on demand at certain points during it's rotation.

This would create greater rotational forces only in one direction. I'm not even saying this is possible, or would even apply to moving large objects against the forces of gravity, but if this was possible, could it create continuous acceleration in lets say the void of space at minimum?

I've have several theories for how this type of rotation could be implemented, does this concept even make sense, even if somewhat theoretical, even if flawed, limited, or could be improved?

Comment: An out of balance washing machine can dance around the floor. A tire that is not balanced can bounce up and down. So yes it can be done. But the usual thing is to try not to.

Comment: But if you could concentrate and direct it, you could use those forces to apply more predictable acceleration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object floating in empty space cannot use any internal motion to change the trajectory of its centre of mass. At most, it can use internal motions to change its configuration or shape or orientation. To change the trajectory of its centre of mass, the object would have to eject some part of itself, in which case the reaction force will send the object in the opposite direction.

The same applies to an object on a smooth surface. However, an object on a surface with friction *can* use internal motions and friction to move itself. For example, it could move a large mass quickly from one end of itself to the other then bring the mass back slowly to its starting position.

Comment: I understand what you're saying and from my general but light understanding of physics, this is what I would have thought too. But putting aside the current laws of physics for the sake of experimentation, and accepting that sometimes we make new discoveries, do you understand why I think this would work? Would this be possible with some form of stored energy taken into account?

Comment: This site deals with mainstream physics. As such, we don't "put aside the current laws of physics". In  support of  gandalf61 answer, To quote from the following web site:

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Newt.html

“A system cannot "bootstrap" itself into motion with purely internal forces - to achieve a net force and an acceleration, it must interact with an object external to itself.”

Comment: I thought of an example. In an uninflated rolling wheel, the tread is pushed outward by centrifugal force. The faster it turns the greater the force. This causes the patch in contact with the road to push the road away. If it spins fast enough, the force pushing the road away can be greater than the weight of the wheel. The tread will support the wheel even though the tire is not inflated. Thus centrifugal force is used to generate an upward force on the wheel.